# Add or remove a location directive from clojure

Tags: nginx, clojure

Is it possible to dynamically add/remove a `location` directive using [`nginx-clojure`](https://github.com/nginx-clojure/nginx-clojure) or some other libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible using nginx-clojure